# How to horizontally centralize a semantic-ui-react form

Tags: forms, reactjs, semantic-ui

I am working on a front-end project using [semantic-ui-react](http://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form) node pacakage. I am new to using this, and I am having issues to horizontally centralize the form. Below is how I am rendering the form.

```
render(){
  const accessCodeLb='Access Code'
  const passwordLb='Password'
  const {accessCodeError,passwordError}=this.state
  return(
  <div>
    <Header as='h2' icon textAlign='center'>
      <Icon name='write' circular/>
      <Header.Content>
        {signUpLb}
      </Header.Content>
    </Header>
    <Grid stackable page columns={16}>
      <Grid.Column width={2}></Grid.Column>
      <Grid.Column width={12}>
        <Form size='small' key='small'>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Field width={4} control={Input} name='accessCode' error={accessCodeError}
            placeholder={accessCodeLb} onChange={this.onChange}/>
          </Form.Group>
          <Form.Group>
            <Form.Field width={4} control={Input} name='password' error={passwordError}
             type='password' placeholder={passwordLb} onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
          <Button primary type='submit' onClick={this.onSubmit}>Login</Button>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
     </Grid.Column>
     <Grid.Column width={2}></Grid.Column>
   </Grid>
 </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

NOTE: Currently Semantic UI React is not yet compatible with the latest 2.3 version of Semantic UI styles. See #2250 for more info.

Here's the link: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/2550

The following solved my issue with centering the display of the modal.

```
.ui.dimmer {
  display: flex !important;
}

.ui.modal {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally did it like below:

```
render(){
  const accessCodeLb='Access Code'
  const passwordLb='Password'
  const {accessCodeError,passwordError}=this.state
  return(
    <div>
      <Header as='h2' icon textAlign='center'>
         <Icon name='write' circular/>
         <Header.Content>
            {signUpLb}
         </Header.Content>
     </Header>
     <Grid columns={16}>
        <Grid.Column width={6}></Grid.Column>
        <Grid.Column width={4}>
          <Form size='small' key='small'>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Field width={16} control={Input} name='accessCode' error={accessCodeError} placeholder={accessCodeLb} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
                <Form.Field width={16} control={Input} name='password' error={passwordError} type='password' placeholder={passwordLb} onChange={this.onChange}/>
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group>
               <Form.Field as={Button} width={8}/>
               <Form.Field as={Button} width={8}primary type='submit' onClick={this.onSubmit}>Login</Form.Field>
            </Form.Group>
          </Form>
       </Grid.Column>
       <Grid.Column width={6}></Grid.Column>
    </Grid>
   </div>
   )
  }
```